# A batch file that searches the computer for multiple items

Tags: batch-file

I made a batch script but it seems to be kind of broken in the sense that when I run it only one of the searches comes up in the console. All I need is a batch script that searches the C:\ for strings and file names. Here is what I have.

```
@echo off
findstr /m "vape" *.* > vf-log.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo.
echo Vape strings found.
) else (
echo.
echo No strings found.
)
dir /S C:\vape.* > vf-log.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo.
echo Vape files found.
) else (
echo.
echo No files found.
)
dir /S C:\harambe.* > vf-log.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo.
echo Harambe files found.
) else (
echo.
echo No files found.
)
dir /S C:\kurium.* > vf-log.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo.
echo Kurium files found.
) else (
echo.
echo No files found.
)
dir /S C:\clicker.* > vf-log.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo.
echo Autoclicker files found.
) else (
echo.
echo No files found.
)
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\vf-log.txt"
pause
```

I'm probably doing something wrong.

---

Edit: I have this now. I have a file in Prefetch called VAPE-LAUNCHER it doesn't pick up even though I'm using dir. Help?

```
@echo off
echo Loading...
echo.
dir C:\vape*.* /s /b >> vf-log.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Files found!
) else (
echo.
echo No files found.
)
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\vf-log.txt"
pause
```

Comment: `>` overwrites your file every time. To append, use `>>`

Comment: it still only says "Vape Strings Found" and nothing else that I tell it to say. Also, can I make the text file cleaner at all? it's just a mash of things.

Comment: `Dir c:\windows\user*.* C:\windows\shell*.*`

Comment: what does this have to do with anything Noodles?

Comment: How to search a hard drive for MULTIPLE names.

Answer (score 0):

`>` means "create this file **ANEW**"
`>>` means "append to this file or create it if it doesn't exist"

BTW - you could try

```
findstr /m /L /c:"string1" /c:"string2" /c:"string3"....
```

or

```
findstr /m /g:"filename.txt" ...
```

to find multiple strings (`filename.txt` contains strings one-to-a-line)

and equally,

```
dir /s c:\string1.* c:\string1.* ....
```

will show you multiple filemask-matches

and `dir /s /b....` will give you filenames-only (like from `findstr /m`)

Comment: Missing file : possibly the file has the `hidden` or `system` attribute set, and you'd need to re-run the `dir` with the `/ah` or `/as` switch. If no-go here, look very carefully at the file's name. Possibly do a `dir` which will show the filename, redirect the `dir` output to a text file and examine the result using a decent editor like `editplus` or use a hex-editor to ensure that the filename isn't mangled in some way.